# Prediction with regression equation in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

First of all let me tell you I'm very new to R, so my question might sounds weird to you, I want to predict the weight of an individual from the height. For that I need to find the equation of the regression line (in the following form) for this problem:

Weight = intercept + (slope) x Height

I've the following form of data ?

Any idea about how to find regression line equation

```
dat <- read.table(text = "SampleNo,Height,Weight
                          1,65.78,112.99
                          2,71.52,136.49
                          3,69.40,153.03
                          4,68.22,142.34
                          5,67.79,144.30
                          6,68.70,123.30
                          7,69.80,141.49
                          8,70.01,136.46
                          9,67.90,112.37", 
                  sep = ",", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the `lm` function.

```
lm1 <- lm(Weight ~ Height, data = dat )
```

I want to predict `Weight` as a function of `Height` so I use the syntax `Weight ~ Height`.

Finally, I run the `coefficients` function on the `lm1` object to get the coefficient for `Height` and the intercept.

```
coefficients(lm1)
    (Intercept)      Height 
    -177.650244    4.525168
```

If I want to predict the result for `Weight` for a certain set of `Heights`, I can do that with the following:

```
> predict(lm1, newdata = data.frame((Height = c(65, 68.5, 71.6))))
       1        2        3 
116.4857 132.3238 146.3518
```

You can get additional information about the fit using the `summary` function on the `lm1` object. This will provide R^2 values, more info on the estimates, etc...

```
summary(lm1)

Call:
lm(formula = Weight ~ Height, data = vals)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-17.239  -9.500  -2.697  11.283  16.634 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -177.650    193.247  -0.919    0.389
Height         4.525      2.808   1.611    0.151

Residual standard error: 13.03 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2705,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1663 
F-statistic: 2.596 on 1 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.1512
```

A great (free) resource for regression and many other machine learning techniques in R can be found [here](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/). It's a great book to learn about stats and how to implement those methods in R.

Comment: what would be the equation of regression line ?

Comment: I just need to find equation as I've to estimate the weights of people with heights 65 inches, 68.5 inches and 71.6 inches.
so what would be the equation ?

Comment: I mean just a generic equation, in which i just put the heights of people and it conjectures the weight of people.

Comment: can you please tell me how did you found this equation ?

Comment: I will clarify the method in my actual response.